# Easy analytics dashboard using python

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash, dashboard, apache-superset, jupyterhub

I'm working on a project where I run some python code on data on my local machine to generate an analytics dashboard to be shared with some business clients. These users don't know python and the dashboard should be interactive and support filtering options where the user can choose some options and the dashboard view is recomputed based on this. I'm exploring these options right now:

1. Connect to data db and use Superset or Dash to visualise the plots. Since I'm not very familiar working with webapps, I'm struggling a bit to share the dashboards I created with users and managing permissions. Is there a way where I can embed the dashboards using inline html that would also support recomputation of aggregation fields based on filter attributes (eg- mean/median). Or do I need to host them and provide access to the dashboard to each user?
2. Create the report in the form of a juputer-notebook with widgets that a user can select. What's the best way to share these notebooks? I considered Binder but not sure how to connect my db with it. Jupyterhub seems to expose the entire code that's something I don't want.

Some additional details: the underlying datasets used are not too big and the number of business users would be less than 20. Basically, I would like to explore options where the learning curve is not too high and avoid the server hosting route if possible.

Please let me know if this is achievable or if there are other options available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your questions. But what we do in my organisation is to compile dash-dashboards with `pyinstaller` to one single `.exe`. This can the be distributed in exchange-folders etc.
So you'll end up with a production-ready product where the user doesn't need to know any programming skills.